# Wi-fi driver is not supported by wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to a WPA-encrypted wireless network from the console. I am using an ALFA AWUS036ACH wi-fi adapter. So I have created the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` which contains the following:

```
network={
    ssid="my_network_name"
    psk="my_pass"
}
```

Then ran `lshw -C network` as root and got

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx00c0caaba0be
       serial: 00:c0:ca:ab:a0:be
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

So I assume my driver is `rtl88XXau`, but when I run (as root)

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D rtl88XXau -i wlx00c0caaba0be -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I get the following output

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlx00c0caaba0be: Unsupported driver 'rtl88XXau'
```

And the wi-fi does not connect. When I try to specify `wext` as my driver, the output is

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
```

My Ubuntu GUI, however, allows me to use this card and there are no problems with connecting to an access point. What is wrong with the way I try to do it in terminal?

Comment: Any updates on this?